# Console.Log() is executed before the actual data collected in code

Tags: node.js, jasmine, protractor

I am trying to print the value on console by using console.log() method.
I have used this method after getting the desired value to be printed, however this method prints `Searched Accession:___::[object Object]` message.

```
browser.driver.findElement(by.xpath('//*[@id="dataTable_filter"]/label/input')).sendKeys('17-01717');
browser.sleep(5000);
var accession= element.all(by.xpath('//*[@id="dataTable"]/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/a')).getText();
expect(accession).toContain('17-01717');
console.log('*****Searched Accession:___::'+accession);
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Yes, you are trying to concatenate the object with a string to the log which calls it's `toString` method which will print `[object Object]` if you want to log the contents of the objects alongside the string then you need `console.log('*****Searched Accession:___::', accession);`  

I won't be posting this as an answer as you could have easily found this by viewing the docs, please do some further research next time before consulting SO :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please go to [www.protractortest.org](http://www.protractortest.org/#/) and do the [Tutorial](http://www.protractortest.org/#/tutorial), check the [Styleguide](http://www.protractortest.org/#/style-guide) (especially the Locator Strategies) and the [API](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api).

Though we like to help on SO, it's just too obvious that you didn't put any effort in researching anything about Protractor. Your code example contains a lot of errors and bad practices:

- `browser.driver.findElement()` is kind of replaced by `element()` or `$()`
- search rather `by.css` than `by.xpath` - it's much more reliable
- `browser.sleep()` is never needed. It's possible with `browser.wait()` and [`ExpectedConditions`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorExpectedConditions)
- you can't do `getText()` from `element.all()`, because `element.all()` returns a Promise, which resolves in an Array

**Starter Bonus, here your code in a potentially working way**

```
$('#dataTable_filter label input').sendKeys('17-01717');
let accession= $$('#dataTable tbody tr td a').first();
accession.getText().then(function(txt){
    console.log('*****Searched Accession:___::'+txt);
});
expect(accession.getText()).toContain('17-01717');
```

you actually don't need the `console,log()`, but if you'd like to print the text you receive from `getText()`, you need to do `then()` in order to resolve the promise first.

**The thing with Promises**

Apparently you're not aware, how `Promises` work. In very short: Many JavaScript/Jasmine/Protractor commands return first promises, only few commands get immediately executed. It's as if you run through your code twice:

In the first run the `Promise`-commands will answer "I promise to do it later" and the execution commands will answer "doing it - done!".

Then in the (imaginary) second run all your `Promise`-commands will answer "doing it now - done", but the execution commands will answer "did it already, I don't to anything any more".

So all in all your `console.log()` is the only immediately executed line of code... all other lines get executed in second run.

Comment: Hi,
I tried with above code and got the desired console.log() output, however my test is failed with msg:
---
Started
**Searched Accession:___::17-01717
F
Failures:
1) Page should have searched Accesion
  Message:
    Expected undefined to contain '17-01717'.
----------
code:
 $(('#dataTable_filter label input')).sendKeys('17-01717');
        let accession= $$('#dataTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td.sorting_1 > a').first().getText().then(function(txt){
            console.log('*****Searched Accession:___::'+txt);
        });
        expect(accession).toContain('17-01717');

Comment: I updated my answer; the code should now work. The `.then()` and `expect()` resolve promises inside. And `getText()` returns a promise. (Before the value `accession` didn't return anything anymore as there was no `return` inside the already resolved promise).